# jwplayer append file to playlist

Tags: jwplayer, playlists

looking at the documentation for jwplayer I can't find any reference on how to append a file to an existing playlist.

The spec is for a user to be able to add a media file to the playlist while browsing the website without interrupting playback of current file

`player.getPlaylist().push({file:'test.mp3', 'title':"test"})` does not work (wouldn't expect it work really based on the method's name), and the only way seems to be by reloading the playlist as described here: [How to load playlist without restart the current playing video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183926/how-to-load-playlist-without-restart-the-current-playing-video)

but it feels wrong and will probably prevent a seamless media addition.

The other option would be to write some custom playlist logic but i'd rather avoid this and use jwplayers own playlist controls

Does anyone have a better way to do this?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: it seems that there isn't an easy way to do it (apart from writing some custom logic) with the current jwplayer api (version 6xx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code that will do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Add to Playlist</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.longtailvideo.com/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("container").setup({
        height: 254,
        width: 720,
        file: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/nPripu9l-60830.mp4",
        image: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/thumbs/nPripu9l-320.jpg",
        title: "Big Buck Bunny trailer",
        listbar: {
        position: "right",
        size: 280,
        },
        primary: 'flash'
    }); 
    function addVideo(videoUrl, videoThumb, videoTitle) {
        var playlist = jwplayer().getPlaylist();
        var newItem = {
            file: videoUrl,
            image: videoThumb,
            title: videoTitle
        };
        playlist.push(newItem);
        jwplayer().load(playlist);
    }
</script>
<p>Click on one of the links below to add an item to the player:</p>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/16026/loading-a-playlist-into-the-player#" onclick="addVideo('http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/yj1shGJB-60830.mp4', 'http://content.bitsontherun.com/thumbs/yj1shGJB-320.jpg', 'Sintel trailer'); return false;">Add the Sintel trailer to the playlist</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/16026/loading-a-playlist-into-the-player#" onclick="addVideo('http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/i8oQD9zd-kNspJqnJ.mp4', 'http://content.bitsontherun.com/thumbs/i8oQD9zd-640.jpg', 'Tears of Steel'); return false;">Add the Tears of Steel trailer to the playlist</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Ethan, thanks for your answer, but that's just like the other solution I found here on SO

Comment: Hm, when it loads the new item to the playlist, the load will always stop the playback I'm afraid.

Comment: Simply using `jwplayer().getPlaylist().push()` used to work in version 6.2. You didn't need to call `load()`. Playback was unaffected and it just played the appended video when playback got to the end. But it's been broken in the last few versions. Can you add this functionality back?

Comment: If I have some time, I'll try to make an example. But I'm pretty sure it's related to [this issue](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/javascript-interaction/32497/getplaylistitemindex-undefined/). I don't know the source well enough to say for sure, but in that thread, JeroenW mentioned that a bunch of undocumented methods were cleaned up. Since I've never seen any actual documentation for `push()`, it may have been blown away also. This definitely worked on v6.2. I have production code that uses it. I've tried to upgrade, but these 2 issues have blocked me.