# Why resuming media doesn't work after a playlist is loaded in JW Player 6.9?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I'm trying to push a new item to a JW Player playlist then update the player on-the-fly, using the Javascript API.

I can easily do that by using:

```
var newItem = {}; // media properties...
var playlist = jwplayer().getPlaylist();
playlist.push(newItem);
jwplayer().load(playlist);
```

And it works! The new item is succesfully added. However, JW Player pauses when I load the new playlist.

There's an event that is fired right when a new playlist is loaded into the player (after `.load()` method), which is `.onPlaylist()`. I thought I could resume playing at this moment... However, `.play()` just doesn't work here.

```
jwplayer().onPlaylist(function() {
  jwplayer().play();
});
```

I have also tried calling `.seek()` instead of play, which seems to work for some people, but nothing happened.

Why is it wrong? Is there another way for resuming media after loading a new playlist?

**Edit:**

I see that some people [achieved this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183926/how-to-load-playlist-without-restart-the-current-playing-video), but I think they were using earlier versions of JW Player since their solution isn't working for me.

**Edit 2:**

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4fbm13fz/

Comment: You should open an issue with the maintainers of that library

Comment: Yes, Ethan. Could you please check this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/4fbm13fz/

Comment: Ah, I see. You can't really resume a playlist after a video is loaded, but I wrote something that is a little bit hacky that tries to simulate this for at least html5 mode. https://github.com/emaxsaun/addtoplaylist, and the demo - http://www.pluginsbyethan.com/github/addtoplaylist.html